# wget mirror not getting everything

Tags: web, wget, mirroring

I'm running

```
 wget -mk --no-check-certificate https://singpolyma.net/
```

And it seems to be pulling down all the pages and resources and blog posts, but it's missing a large number of the /actionstream/* URIs.  It gets some of them, and each of these pages has prev/next links which should mean it can get all of them, but it doesn't.  No errors in the output.

I tried changing to start at `https://singpolyma.net/actionstream/reply-httpidenti-canotice72478545-russellmcormond-thats/` but that didn't work either, it in fact got even *less* of the /actionstream/* items.

There must be some switch that I'm missing.  I thought the -l inf from -m would do it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most likely hit by [bug #31354: wget does not parse html files linked by link rel="..."](http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?31354). Fix is already in trunk for some time (since [r2434](http://bzr.savannah.gnu.org/lh/wget/trunk/revision/2434)). Below I pasted excerpt from ChangeLog regarding it.

```
2010-10-18  Manfred Koizar  (tiny change)

    * html-url.c (tag_handle_link): Do not assume external links type
    to be always "text/html".
```

Last officially released version is unfortunately pretty old (1.12 came out in September 2009), so you have to download and build more recent version. GNU software has [alpha.gnu.org/gnu](http://alpha.gnu.org/gnu/wget/) site, where you can obtain more recent versions.

Comment: This ChangeLog entry is one of those stealth examples, where you smuggle more than it seems, w/o any proper note. Really BAD practice! Tiny change, huh?

Comment: I updated to 1.12-2474 and get the same problem.  There are clearly links to the pages that did not get downloaded in the ones that did.  I'm very confused.

Comment: @singpolyma Can you tell what's missing in my output of `wget -mk --no-check-certificate --spider -o log 'https://singpolyma.net/actionstream/reply-httpidenti-canotice72478545-russellmcormond-thats/'; grep '^--' log | gzip > singpolyma.net-urls.gz` available at [http://min.us/mvoZpQV](http://min.us/mvoZpQV)? BTW there is a lot of read errors, and some links are broken (46 in my wget run).

Comment: It seems possible nothing is missing there.  grep '/actionstream/' your-log | grep -v try: | wc -l says 10201 which seems plausible, unlike the < 200 that I get downloaded when I run without --spider.  What are they retries?  Are those the webserver timing out?

Comment: After seeing your log I thought to try adding -t inf    After doing so wget sucks up RAM really fast and eventually the kernel kills it...

Comment: Strange. Sorry for asking that (mistakes sometimes happen), but are you sure you were running newly compiled wget and not the old one? (you should invoke `hash -r` and to be more safe use direct path to new `wget` file)  Adding `-l inf` shouldn't change anything, because `-m` automatically adds it. Retries happend if there were read errors, like `2011-05-06 18:06:46 (30.2 KB/s) - Read error at byte 8027 (Success.).Retrying`. There is also other bug that may be hitting you. I haven't checked whether you have big non-html files,  if yes then there is https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?20496

Comment: I was running the new one.  I checked with wget --version before I ran it and it said 1.12-2474    Read error means the connection was terminated or what?  The idea with adding -t inf was that maybe it was being forced to retry more than 20 times, as in your log a few places.

Comment: Interesting call on the RAM issue.  I'll try again sometime soon and look into if it start to go crazy on a particular large file or something :)

Comment: Sorry, I misread you. You told about `-t inf` and I've seen it as `-l inf`...

Comment: wget by default has `tries = 20` (which was usually enough to successfully download files from your site) and I also have `waitretry = 10` in my `/etc/wgetrc` (don't remember the default value) to prevent useless delays.

Comment: Just a note. These errors I mentioned before are possibly only at my side. I haven't really investigated it yet, but I'm getting them on totally different site now. Sorry for bringing up this subject before.

Comment: @singpolyma wget 1.12 (r2297) is free from the `HTTP request sent, awaiting response... Read error (Success.) in headers.` issue and it also have been fixed just after r2474, the last release available via alpha.gnu.org. I've suggested Giuseppe (current wget maintainer) to upload more recent version there (r2498 is the latest atm). In the meantime, if you don't want to play with bazaar, I've uploaded already bootstrapped wget sources for you: http://paste.przemoc.net/wget/wget-1.12-2498.tar.bz2  Check it, because presumably some of your problems will vanish with the most recent version.

Comment: So, I'll have to try on a different machine, but on the one that I originally had the problem on I cannot try using this version of the code.  It very quickly blows up to consume over 50% of the RAM